# Spring Security OIDC and JWT instead of session

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

We are considering going stateless, i.e. using JWTs instead of sessions. But it seems to be tricky with OIDC and Spring Security. Some blog posts, e.g. Spring Lemon[1], suggest subclassing several of Spring's OIDC classes and make use of filters for issuing signed JWTs after the user has been authenticated, but they are based on older versions before `.oauth2ResourceServer()` became available as a configurable class in security config.

Today our users are being authenticated by using OIDC, but we also provide an API, and thus we have API users as well. At the time of writing, we are rewriting the application to become more RESTful. More logic will be placed in frontend, and backend will only provide several APIs. To simplify the model even further, our idea is to use JWTs instead of session, for both API and OIDC users.

What is the best approach? Still use sessions for the end users (and only use JWTs for API users) or try to build a stateless application using JWTs for all users instead? Is Spring Lemon the right way to go? Should we also use `oauth2ResourceServer` in our config class for validating the JWTs?

[1] Spring Lemon: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-5-oauth-20-login-and-signup-in-stas

Comment: The Spring Lemon link seems to be broken, so I'm posting a new one: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-5-oauth-20-login-and-signup-in-sta

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer...

Go stateless with resource servers (REST APIs secured with access token). No session makes scalability much easier and insensible to CSRF attacks (protection against which you can disable as soon as you select "stateless" session-management).

However, OAuth2 resource servers are queried by OAuth2 clients and it is not recommended any more to configure web or mobile apps as "public" OAuth2 clients: public clients are more dangerous than confidential ones and it is way safer to hide tokens from the internet, mobile phones, web browsers and the code that runs on it. In the end, using sessions with http-only secured cookies is safer (provided that CSRF protection is enabled).

The best option for mobile and Javascript based front-ends to consume stateless resource servers seams to introduce a middleware on the server (called **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend), configured as an OAuth2 client responsible for:

- handling authorization_code flow (login)
- storing tokens in sessions
- replacing session cookie with access token before forwarding a request to a resource server.

Of course, such a BFF is stateful and must be protected against CSRF.

`spring-cloud-gateway` can easily be configured as BFF with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `TokenRelay=` filter. **I wrote [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).**